# Suppress warning for <webview>: A new window was blocked

Tags: google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app

I know I can't open a new window from a Chrome App webview (at least without jumping through additional hoops). I can live with that - indeed I count on it in one use case. I just want to get rid of the warning that appears in the console.

Any ideas how I can suppress the warning message?

Comment: Um, who would look at the warnings in a console in a Chrome App? It's not even easy to invoke it.

Comment: Me. The warning makes it harder to read than it is to invoke.

Comment: Do you even explicitly process the `newwindow` request? Also, an example of such a warning will be helpful

Comment: The warning is "<webview>: A new window was blocked". Yes I process the newwindow request. The warning is not helpful because I know exactly what happened - I programmed it to happen.

Comment: Would be a good idea to edit the question to include that info.